# probability with percentage independence

Tags: probability

There is 15% chance of choosing blue marble, 65% chance of choosing a purple marble, and 20% chance of choosing a black marble, there will be 18 total draws,

what is the probability that you will choose exactly 12 purple marbles?

Also, what is the probability you will choose 4 blue, 11 purple, and 3 black?

for 12 purple, I did (.65)^12 x (1-.65)^6 but my answer is wrong, and similar method for second part,

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what you've done is the probability of choosing 12 purple marbles *first*, and *then* 6 non-purple marbles. To fix this, you have to multiply by the number of ways you can choose *which* of the 18 marbles are to be purple, which is ${18 \choose 12}$.

Comment: I tried doing the same for the second part, but it's not working, ffor 4 blue, 11 purple, and 3 black

Comment: Did you get the first part right? Could you show me your working so far for that one?

Comment: yes, I did my previous work and multiplied it by 18C12 = 18564 x .0056 x .0018 = .191

Comment: Yep - can you please show me what you've done for the second part? Edit: sorry I didn't make that clear in my comment before :)

Comment: nevermind, this is what I did:

Comment: (.15 ^4  x 18C4) (.2^3 x 18C3) (.65^11 x 18C11)

Comment: After you've chosen the 4 blue marbles, you only have 14 left, so your next one should be ${14 \choose 3}$. Then after you've done that, the rest of them *have* to be purple, so you don't have to multiply anything: but if you were to go through with it, it'd be ${11 \choose 11} = 1$.

Comment: I still don't get the right answer, this time I did

Comment: (.15 ^4 x 18C4) (.2^3 x 14C3) (.65^11 x 11C11), answer is supposed to be .04

Comment: Hmm, that looks okay to me, and it agrees with the other answer. What's the answer supposed to be? Have you checked your calculations?

Comment: Yeah, it seems correct: check your calculations. Wolfram link's broken, so you might have to copypaste: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=18%21%2F%284%21*11%21*3%21%29+*+0.15%5E4+*+0.65%5E11+*+0.2%5E3

Answer (score 1):

You can model the problem with the [multinomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function). Let $X=(X_i)$ and $X_i$ be the number of marbles of color $i\in$ {blue, purple, black}. Then the random vector $X$ is multinomially distributed with parameters $p_i$ and $n=18$. Thus the pmf of $X$ is $$P(X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2, X_3=x_3)=\dfrac{n!}{x_1!x_2!x_3!}0.15^{x_1}0.65^{x_2}0.2^{x_3}$$ You want to calculate the probabilities

1. $P(X_2=12)$ and
2. $P(X_1=4, X_2=11, X_3=3)$

   For the first one you can avoid the summation if you consider the binomial random variable $X_2$ wich denotes the number of purple marbles only, with parameters $p=0.65$ and $n=18$. Thus the formula is $$P(X_2=12)=\dbinom{18}{12}0.65^{12}0.35^6$$

The second can be found directly by substituting in the pmf of $X$:

$$P(X_1=4, X_2=11, X_3=3)=\dfrac{18!}{4!11!3!}0.15^{4}0.65^{11}0.2^{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

An interesting approximation / variation of part one would be to view the ratio of purple marbles to non purple marbles as $65$% vs. $35$% respectively and then "fill" a large container with that ratio so like $1000$ marbles with $650$ of them being purple and $350$ of them being nonpurple.  Then the answer would simply be :

${\binom {650} {12} * {\binom {350} 6}} / {\binom {1000} {18}}$ which is less than $1$% high vs. the correct answer.

If you want more accuracy, increase the number of marbles so you could have:

${\binom {6500} {12} * {\binom {3500} 6}} / {\binom {10000} {18}}$ which is less than $0.1$% high vs. the correct answer.